# How to remove spaces between the string which is extracted from sitecore

Tags: c#

Hi Please see the below field I extracted from the sitecore. I dont want any spaces betwwen paragraphs or lines just need to have the plain strings:

```
    Meet nearly any application need
This extra large format flatbed printer lets you print on rigid panels up to 2.5 m x 3.05 m, and up to 50.8 mm thick; and flexible rolls up to 220 cm wide. You can even print on irregularly-shaped, reasonably flat objects, by simply placing them on the flatbed printer table.
If a job can be printed digitally, it most likely can be produced on an Océ Arizona 440 XT UV flatbed printer. With the ability to print on a wide variety of media and objects in full colour, print service providers can capture revenue from applications ranging from standard sign and display (POP/POS, retail signage) to speciality flatbed printing applications.

The right partner for building your business
Océ Display Graphics is committed to helping you grow your business in today's competitive environment. That's why we continue to invest and innovate in our market-leading UV flatbed printers. So you get the right technologies, the right advice and the right support to help you move forward. 

Exceptional print quality, productivity improvements

  Océ VariaDot® imaging technology for superior image quality 
  Active pixel placement compensation for assured image sharpness, density and uniformity around the entire flatbed or across the Roll Media Option 
  Six user-selectable vacuum zones designed to match most standard-sized graphics arts media without masking 
  Batch mode for streamlining multi-layered jobs or facilitating set collation 
  Print speeds of up to 20.3 square metres per hour of high quality production capacity over a broad range of media and applications 
  Upgrade at any time to an Océ Arizona 460 GT model to add White Ink and Varnish capability, or upgrade to an Océ Arizona 480 GT model to take advantage of CM2 printing that offers even higher quality at faster speeds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find if you got there any `\n` , `\t` , `<p>` , `<BR>` 
And then split your String with these elements above using `split()` or `SrtingTokenzier`